# How can we SSH to a Google Cloud VM from Mac terminal using public key generated on the VM?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

We wanted to connect to a Google Cloud VM using a public key generated on the VM from a Mac Terminal. But we see the below error

```
konathal:.ssh konathal$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/runnhostkey1.pub suren@1.2.3.4

Load key "/Users/konathal/.ssh/runnhostkey1.pub": invalid format
suren@1.2.3.4: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

**What we did?**

Following the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys

1.We created a new public key on Google Cloud VM as

```
~/.ssh/runnhostkey1
~/.ssh/runnhostkey1.pub
```

2.Added the public key `runnhostkey1.pub` contents to VM > Edit > SSH Keys

3.Created a new file in local mac and copied the contents of the public key

```
$ vi ~/.ssh/runnhostkey1.pub
$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/runnhostkey1.pub
```

We are not able to connect to the VM using `$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/runnhostkey1.pub suren@1.2.3.4`

What are we missing?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the public key to connect via SSH. You must use the private key.

The public key is used by the VM to verify your authorization to connect.

Most likely your private key is: `~/.ssh/runnhostkey1`

Answer (score 1):

We found the issue and the solution:

1)The owner & group of the keys (pubic and private) files should be owned by the user who is used to generate the keys. In our case, we were logged in as **root** but created the keys with user **suren**.

**Solution**

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/runnkey -C suren` but we ran this logged in as `root` so the files has the owner as `root`. A quick fix was to change the ownership

`chown suren:suren ~/.ssh/runnkey` and `chown suren:suren ~/.ssh/runnkey.pub`

2)Add the public keys to **/.ssh/authorised_keys**.

Example `cat ~/.ssh/runnkey.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

3)Change the permissions for files

```
 chmod 0700 /.ssh/authorised_keys
 chmod 0600 /.ssh/runnkey
 chmod 0600 /.ssh/runnkey
```

4)Add the keys to VM instance. Compute Engine > VM Instances > [VM you'd like to access] > Edit > SSH Keys. Copy the text (`vi ~/.ssh/runnkey.pub` copy) of public key and add paste here. Save.

5)Create files `runnkey` and `runnkey.pub` on your local mac under `/.ssh` folder and copy contents from respective files on the server.

Sample test commands:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/runnkey.pub suren@1.2.3.4
scp -i ~/.ssh/runnkey.pub /Downloads/ship.png suren@1.2.3.4:/home/temp
```

The above 1,2,3 are mentioned in [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser) under section **The permissions on $HOME or $HOME/.ssh directory of the connecting user are wrong.**